# What is the process for submitting a github pull request for a modification to an earlier tagged version of a repository?

Tags: git, github

I have created a patch, in a fork, for an older version of a project hosted on github.  Having checked out the tag for the version I'm fixing, committing my change and creating a new tag, I'm not sure how to proceed.  Pull request seem to only compare branches.

Is there a process for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Your pull request will merge with the existing head of the project, or whatever branch you specify. If the project has a branch devoted to that version, you can target that branch in your pull request.

Comment: So this is a good reason to keep branches around for older versions.